# gradle get value from extension (pass as input to task)

Tags: plugins, gradle

I have following code in my plugin:

```
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {

        project.extensions.create(EXTENSION,TestExtension)

        project.task("task1") << {
            println "Task 1"
            println(project.mmm.test)
            def extension = project.extensions.findByName(EXTENSION)
            println(extension.test)
        }

        project.task("task2",type: TestTask) {
            println "Task 2 "
            def extension = project.extensions.findByName(EXTENSION)
//            conventionMapping.test = {extension.test}
//            println(project.extensions.findByName(EXTENSION).test)
//            test = "test"

        }
    }
```

In task 1 extension.test return correct value. However in task2 extension.test always return null. What I am doing wrong? Is there a better way to pass some of the extensions values as input for task? I am using gradle 1.12 with jdk 1.8 on Mac. Best Regards

Edit :correct version:

```
   project.task("task2", type: TestTask) {
        project.afterEvaluate {
            def extension = project.extensions.findByName(EXTENSION)
            println(project.extensions.findByName(EXTENSION).test)
            test = project.extensions.findByName(EXTENSION).test
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`task1` prints the value at execution time (notice the `<<`), `task2` at configuration time (before the rest of the build script after the `apply plugin: ...` has been evaluated). This explains why the `println` for task1 works as expected, and the `println` for task2 doesn't.

However, configuring a task at execution time is too late. Instead, a plugin needs to defer reading user-provided values until the end of the configuration phase (after build scripts have been evaluated, but before any task has been executed). There are several techniques for doing so. One of the simpler ones is to wrap any such read access with `project.afterEvaluate { ... }`.

Comment: You mean to wrap only wrap reading of extensions in afterEvaluate or entire task definition? When I wrapped entire task it is working correctly. Thanks

Comment: Only reading of user-provided values. When a plugin, say, adds a task, it cannot defer this as otherwise the user cannot reconfigure the task in the remainder of the build script.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer** as some time has passed and Gradle evolved its concepts and its syntax in the meantime.

To use up-to-date and optimally configured task you should use following syntax:

```
tasks.register("task1") {
  doLast {
    def extension = project.extensions.findByName(EXTENSION)
    println(project.extensions.findByName(EXTENSION).test)
    test = project.extensions.findByName(EXTENSION).test
  }
}
```

[Task Action](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:configuring_tasks):

> A task has both configuration and actions. When using the `doLast`, you
> are simply using a shortcut to define an action. Code defined in the
> configuration section of your task will get executed during the
> configuration phase of the build regardless of what task was targeted.

[Deprecated << Operator](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-find-method-leftshift-for-arguments-on-task-of-type-org-gradle-api-defaulttask/30614)

`<<` was deprecated in 4.x and removed in 5.0. See task action (`doLast`) on how to evaluate task logic at execution phase when all extensions and configurations should be evaluated.

[Task Configuration Avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:how_does_it_work)

To avoid the cost of creating a task if this won't be executed on your invoked Gradle command `TaskContainer.register(String)` method.

[Avoid afterEvaluate](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-5-0-rc1-and-afterevaluate/29401)

afterEvaluate should in most cases be avoided, see @sterling's comments from the link. You have now the possibility to evaluate task action part in execution phase, and additionally you can also rely on [Task Inputs/Outputs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs) with the combination of [Lazy Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html).